# Windows 10 installation from boot USB failure

Tags: windows, boot, installation

Hope this question was not already answered, but I don't think so. I found similar cases but nothing exactly like this.
My aim is (it could sound strange, I know) to install Windows 10 on my old Windows XP desktop.
I have a laptop with Windows 10 and I used the Media Creation Tool to generate the Windows 10 ISO. Then I used Rufus to load it into my USB device with the settings below:

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBUBd.png)

Afterwards, I start my PC with the USB device and I press F8 to change the boot, I choose the USB device and a message appears "Press any key to boot from USB...".

I read from other topics then the usual issue is that the keyboard is not recognized, but in my case it is. Indeed I press a random key and the PC restarts, instead of loading the Windows 10 installation. If I don't press any key, Windows XP normally loads.

Do you have any idea? I also tried to prepare the USB device through the Media Creation Tool but it didn't help.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 uses UEFI BIOS and boot and XP is vastly too old to know about this. Your only practical solution is to install Windows 10 normally and then run XP as a virtual machine.

I have that arrangement here and it works just fine.